# Add condition where for mutators in laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, mutators

I want to add condition where for my mutators: age
This is my model:

```
class Player extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'players';

    public $primaryKey ='idplayer';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getAgeAttribute()
    {
         return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['birth'])->age;
    }
}
```

and this is my Controller  where i want  to and condition for my mutator

```
$data = Player::join('posts','idteam','=','id')
        ->where('age','like','%' . $query . '%')
        ->get()


Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'age' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: You can't, really. Not like this, at least.

Comment: You can not add condition in attributes which does not exists in database